# What is a Well behaved Integral?

Tags: integration

I have been reading a book on neural science but i am stuck in the part of well behaved integral. Exactly what is a well behaved integral and what is its relation with summation?
(I am a beginner)

Comment: It's not a precisely defined term. It could be anywhere from "the integrand is continuous" to "the integrand is discontinuous at only countably many points". It's often used to sweep unnecessary or unwanted complexity under the table. What's the context of that phrase?

Comment: An integral is like a summation, except that the number of summands is infinite and the size of each summand is zero. This idea arises when you define the area under a curve as a kind of limit of the areas under increasingly fine "jagged" approximations of the curve. This is the basic idea but the theory goes quite a lot further than this. "Well-behaved" can have various meanings. If you give a bit more context it might be easier to answer your question.